# Load Assembly at runtime, don't block it (and detect changes to that assembly)

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I am trying to load DLLs at runtime into my application:

```
Assembly dllAssembly = Assembly.LoadFile(dllFileInfo.FullName);
assemblies.Add(dllAssembly);
foreach (Type type in dllAssembly.GetExportedTypes())
{
    if (typeof(IPlugin).IsAssignableFrom(type))
    {
        IPlugin i = (IPlugin)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        PluginManager.Add(i);
    }
}
```

However, the issue is that `LoadFile` blocks the assembly (it cannot be replaced as long as IIS is running). This does not happen with the DLLs loaded through references. Even more neat, they can be replaced and IIS automatically restarts the application with the new DLLs.

How can I get the same behaviour for my Plugin DLLs loaded at runtime?

Comment: Consider loading your `Assembly` into another `AppDomain` and then whenever you detect some possible changes just re-create that `AppDomain` and load the new version of the `Assembly`.  That's the only way I can think of right now.

Comment: asp.net uses shadow copying: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/shadow-copy-assemblies. Basically that means assemblies are copied to another directory and loaded from there. When change is detected - IIS restarts whole app domain (that's not part of shadow copying).

Comment: @Evk From your link: "By default, this setting causes all assemblies in the application path to be copied to a download cache before they are loaded." Is it possible to use that shadow copy feature for Assemblies I load at runtime?

Comment: I don't think so. "By default" here means "By default ... copied to download cache" and you can change directory where they are copied to. Your plugins are stored somewhere outside "bin" directory where other dlls are stored?